# How to save links with tags and parameters in TextField

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have this simple Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    body = models.TextField(_('body'))
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, related_name="posts")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want that when I insert in the form the links, then these links are saved in the body from this form:

```
http://www.example.com or www.example.com
```

to this form ( with tag and rel="nofollow" parameter ):

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" rel="nofollow">www.example.com</a>
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to save your form data of a post. You want this post, when rendered later, to be displayed with working HTML links, not just text, like e.g. `stackoverflow.com`.

Why not postpone this step until the moment you render the post? This would keep your database content 'HTML-free' and it's not such a big deal to turn links texts into working HTML links on-the-fly on the server side. You could even turn these text links into HTML links at the client side, e.g. via javascript.

Further reading: [Replace URL with a link using regex in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112012/replace-url-with-a-link-using-regex-in-python)

Comment: yesss, I want to do this with javascript but I don't know. Could you help me ? Right now I am using urlize filter.
Thanks ^_^