# webpy - url autodetect some part of the string to hyperlink

Tags: python, web.py

I've created a sample blog application using webpy. I used some code here([Replace URL with a link using regex in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112012/replace-url-with-a-link-using-regex-in-python)) to replace the URL but when I render the page it won't show the hyperlink but just a plain text

In my template:

```
    <p>
    <i>$datestr(post.posted_on) by $user</i><br/><br/>
    $urlify.formatstring(post.content)
    <p>
```

urlify.py

```
    def formatstring(self, value):
    pat1 = re.compile(r"(^|[\n ])(([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)(/[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)?)", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)

    pat2 = re.compile(r"(^|[\n ])(((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)(/[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)?)", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
    value = pat1.sub(r'\1<a href="\2" target="_blank">\3</a>', value)
    value = pat2.sub(r'\1<a href="http://\2" target="_blank">\3</a>', value)

    return value
```

Example text:

This url will make your life sh!t so don't click this one.<a href="http://www.someurl.com">some url*<*/a>.

Expected after the render of the page shoud be:

This url will make your life sh!t so don't click this one.[some url](http://www.someurl.com).

But the actual is:

This url will make your life sh!t so don't click this one.<a href="http://www.someurl.com">some url*<*/a>.

Url was not change to hyperlink.

EDIT: In my template: 
Instead of $content, it should be $:content to treat the url as hyperlink.

Comment: Don't write "solved" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems to be ok, can you post the arguments you're passing to the `formatstring` method

Comment: I've edited my post to add some details to make my problem more clearer.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what the code does. It takes a url, say `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` and displays a link with only the domain name as text, so in html that would be `<a href="http://www.example.com/foo/bar" target="_blank">http://www.example.com</a>`

Comment: BTW, getting the domain name (the string `"example"` from `http://www.example.com/foo/bar`) is not trivial you can look at this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url

Comment: Yes, you're right I think I misunderstood the function. I already solve my problem. Instead of in my template: $context, it should be $:content to treat the url as hyperlink. BTW thanks for your time.