# Python regex replace anchors

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to rewrite the code I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112670/322764) answer:

```
import re

pat1 = re.compile(r"(^|[\n ])(([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)(/[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)?)", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)

pat2 = re.compile(r"#(^|[\n ])(((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)(/[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)?)", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)


urlstr = 'http://www.example.com/foo/bar.html'

urlstr = pat1.sub(r'\1<a href="\2" target="_blank">\3</a>', urlstr)
urlstr = pat2.sub(r'\1<a href="http:/\2" target="_blank">\3</a>', urlstr)

print urlstr
```

Specifically, I tried this:

```
pattern = re.compile('<a href="javascript:rt\(([0-9]+)\)">Download</a>');

rawtable = pattern.sub(r'\1', rawtable)
```

where I want to replace something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:rt(2061)">Download</a>
```

with this:

```
2061
```

I'd like to do the same with this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ra('Name of object one')"
  title="Some title Text">Name of Object two</a>
```

with just

```
Name of Object two
```

by doing

```
pattern = re.compile('<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ra\('(:?[a-zA-Z0-9 +)'\)" title="Some title Text">([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)</a>');

rawtable = pattern.sub(r'\1', rawtable)
```

but it doesn't work either. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where I want to replace something like this:
>
> ```
> <a href="javascript:rt(2061)">Download</a>
> ```

Your 1st code works. [Test here](http://rextester.com/VQDLC89668)

---

> I'd like to do the same with this:
>
> ```
> <a href="#" onclick="javascript:ra('Name of object one')" title="Some title Text">Name of Object two</a>`
> ```

As for the second, check what I'm marking here:

```
pattern = re.compile('<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ra\('(:?[a-zA-Z0-9 +)'\)" title="Some title Text">([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)</a>');
                                                          | | |         |  ^ unescaped quote (in the string passed to re.compile() )
                                                          | | |         |
                                                          | | ^---------^ you didn't close the character class (as in [a-z]).. add a "]"
                                                          | ^ correct syntax is (?: pattern ) ... However, no point in using it here
                                                          ^ another unescaped quote
```

#### Code:

```
#python 3.4.3
import re;

rawtable = '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ra(\'Name of object one\')" title="Some title Text">Name of Object two</a>';

pattern = re.compile('<a href="#" onclick="javascript:ra\(\'[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\'\)" title="Some title Text">([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)</a>');

rawtable = pattern.sub(r'\1', rawtable);
print(rawtable);
```

[Run this code](http://rextester.com/BPW54950)

#### Output:

```
Name of Object two
```